# Variable becomes undefine in subfunction

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Im using Google Maps javascript api to show a map full of markers of locations. The markers display but once they are clicked on the console gives the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" at `infowindow.setContent('<div><p>'+locations[i][0]+'</p></div>');` . I found that the problem was the script didn't know what `i` was. I have tested to this conclusion by substituting `i` with a number and it works without error. So far I have tried making `i` a global variable and testing its value as `window.i`. It still didn't work, but in console it showed its last count. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
function initialize() {
    var locations = [<?php echo $jscript; ?>];

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.639594, -97.117879),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker = '';
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var geocoder_map = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var addlocat;

        geocoder_map.geocode({'address': locations[i][0]}, function (results, status) {
            if (results) {
                addlocat = results[0].geometry.location;

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: addlocat,
                    map: map
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    return function () {
                        infowindow.setContent('<div><p>' + locations[i][0] + '</p></div>');
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));

            }
        });
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: if you fixed that then what is the problem ? if the console displays the latest value of i that is what it is supposed to do unless you zero it out every time you are done with it

Comment: You should put the IIFE around the function you pass to `geocoder_map.geocode`, not around the event handler. At this moment it's already too late. Also make `marker` local to the `geocode` callback.

Comment: OOOOOh you have a major mistake here. you can't use php inside javascript that is server side inside client, it is not allowed, you can use ajax to populate your field from the server

Comment: @CME64: I think we can assume that the code is part of a file served thorough PHP. Otherwise the while script would not run (syntax error).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem) and [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Comment: have you tried making the locations variable global?

Comment: @CME64: Its still showing the error despite the log even though the array exists and so does the `i`

Comment: @FelixKling you can't place php code inside the script that's for sure, scripts even don't recognize tags too regardless of the big fact that server-side code cannot reside in client-side ..

Comment: @klickagent.ch: Yes I tried that before I posted too.

Comment: @CME64: If the php is echoing javascript then the client side sees no problem

Comment: @CME64: Since the file is served through PHP, the PHP commands are processed first. The result that is sent to the browser could be something like  `var locations = [0,2,3];`. There is no problem to "mix" the code as long as you know when and where it is processed. Besides, the OP said *"I have tested to this conclusion by substituting `i` with a number and it works without error."*, so we can assume the problem is not with how `locations` is built.

Comment: @kdogisthebest try assigning the locations manually and test if that works for you then you only have to use xhtml requests (ajax) read about it here http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp or use jquery's ajax for that to get the date from the server into your javascript ( a request from the client-side must be initiated to get the data from the server's)

Comment: @FelixKling you mean that the server returns the js code with the values in it ,, that's reasonable .. thanks

Comment: @FelixKling If I wanted to rewrite this what would be the best way to structure it?

Comment: I would create a new function containing everything that is currently inside the loop. Then you simply call the function inside the loop like `geocode(i, locations[i]);`. Then you avoid the loop problem. You might have to pass more arguments (e.g. `infowindow`) or make them global (or better, put them in a shared,higher scope that is not global). But pass `i` and the location directly to the function. You could do the same you did for the event handler as well (as I already mentioned), but splitting up the code into multiple functions would improve readability as well IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Following @FelixKling 's structure I busted out this and it worked first try:

```
<script>
function initialize() {
      locations = [<?php echo $jscript; ?>];

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.639594, -97.117879),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    geocode(i, locations[i])
   }
}

function geocode(i, location){
    var geocoder_map = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var addlocat;

    geocoder_map.geocode( { 'address': location[0]}, function(results, status) {
            if(results){
            addlocat = results[0].geometry.location; 

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: addlocat,
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent('<div><p>'+location[0]+'</p></div>');
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Comment: Inside `geocode`, make `marker` local (`var marker = ...;`) and then you can remove the `(function(marker, i) {....}) (marker, i)` part around the event handler.

Comment: Also, you don't actually use `i` in the `geocode()` function, so no need to pass it in as a parameter.